# get previous 12 month data and if not exist then add zero in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
   ###Table                        ###Expected Outpoot

ID |    create_date                 Month | Application | Year
------------------------------      --------------------------
1  |    2017-06-25 10:00:11         10   |      0       | 2016
2  |    2017-06-26 10:00:11         11   |      0       | 2016
3  |    2017-07-02 10:00:11         12   |      0       | 2016
4  |    2017-07-25 10:00:11         1    |      0       | 2017
5  |    2017-08-21 10:00:11         2    |      0       | 2017
6  |    2017-08-22 10:00:11         3    |      0       | 2017
7  |    2017-08-25 10:00:11         4    |      0       | 2017
                                    5    |      0       | 2017
                                    6    |      2       | 2017
                                    7    |      2       | 2017
                                    8    |      3       | 2017
                                    9    |      0       | 2017
```

I am Trying to get the monthly data count from my table.

I am close to solve the issue.Here is the query and result.

```
select date_format(tn.create_date,'%Y-%m') as mon,
count(*) as num
FROM table_name as tn
GROUP BY mon order by mon;


Month       |   Application 
--------------------------------
2017-06     |       2       
2017-07     |       2       
2017-08     |       3
```

So, How do i get my expected output?

Here is the [Query Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9rsSfgz7wX7xHYnnRQnp8w/0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Build a table of all months.
2. `LEFT JOIN` to that table.  Viola, the zeros show up.

Well, you might get `NULLs` instead of zeros.  So use the `IFNULL(application, 0)` function.

BTW, MariaDB has a nifty way to generate sequences of numbers; see "seq".

Answer (score 2):

Just group and order your IDs by both year and month:

```
SELECT date_format(tn.create_date,'%m') as Month, count(ID) as Application, date_format(tn.create_date,'%Y') as Year
FROM test tn
GROUP BY Year,Month
ORDER by Year,Month;
```

to get the data for last 12 month, you'll probably need to create Calendar table as it's already suggested by [~Rick James].

I'd make it with SP to create such table first:

```
CREATE
PROCEDURE .`Calendar`()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cal` (
`month` INT(11) ,
`year` INT(11) 
) ;

SET @counter := -1;
WHILE (DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL @counter MONTH))) < DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH)))) DO 
INSERT INTO Cal SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 MONTH),'%m'),DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), INTERVAL @counter + 1 MONTH),'%Y');
END WHILE;
END
```

Than we can call it and run query on result:

```
CALL Calendar();

SELECT `Cal`.`Month`,IFNULL(COUNT(qr.ID),0) AS Application, `Cal`.`Year`
FROM `Cal`
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID,  MONTH(create_date) AS `Month`,  YEAR(create_date) AS `Year`
    FROM test_data AS tn
    WHERE create_date >  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
    ORDER BY create_date
) qr ON qr.`Month`=`Cal`.`Month`
GROUP BY YEAR,MONTH;
```